# HTMX: disable click event on child nodes

Tags: htmx

I have the following divs and want that when clicking on id="child" it should NOT execute a get to "/modal/closed" and NOT replace the id="modal". That is, do nothing HTMX related.

```html
<div id="modal" hx-trigger="click"
    hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-target="#modal" hx-get="/modal/closed" hx-params="none">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

Right now I have it working using the trigger "click consume" but need to specify an hx-get to an HTTP path that returns nothing (/nop).

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```html
<div id="modal" hx-trigger="click"
    hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-target="#modal" hx-get="/modal/closed" hx-params="none">
    <div hx-trigger="click consume" hx-swap="none" hx-get="/nop">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There isn't an element with `id="click"` in the code you posted so the question is not clear. It would also help to understand why you have the `<div hx-trigger="click consume" hx-swap="none" hx-get="/nop">
    </div>` element there if you want to ignore the click to begin with.

Comment: Yep, it should be id="child", updated the question. The problem is that on the first code example the click over the div with id="child" is captured by the hx attributes on id="modal". I don't want that, I want that any click over id="child" is ignored by htmx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved using the event modifier `"target:#modal"` to indicate we are only interested on the click event originated from the `id="modal"`.

This way clicks over `id="child"` that bubble up to `id="modal"` will be ignored.

```html
<div id="modal" hx-trigger="click target:#modal"
    hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-get="/modal/closed" hx-params="none">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I hadn't use that modifier before, but it seems to do the job. Nice job!.

Comment: This helped when I had a nested `a` element within an `li` one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It works this way due to attribute inheritance in htmx https://htmx.org/docs/#inheritance. Placing the `hx-trigger` attribute on the outer-most div, means that element will listen for the event in all of it's children. When you add the same attribute to a child div with the `consume` modifier it stops the event bubbling up.

So the solution here would be to remove the `hx-trigger` from the outer div. In fact, if what you are trying to do is close a modal, you can add a close button somewhere else in the div. Something like this:

```
<div id="modal">
    <button id="close" hx-trigger="click"
    hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-target="#modal" hx-get="/modal/closed" hx-params="none">Close</button>

    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when you click on the `child` div the event bubbles up and it's not caught by the sibling `close` button.

Comment: Sorry, the names here are kinda confusing... Here "modal" would be the translucent dark background behind the dialog UI that is "child". I want to close the dialog when clicking  on the background so can't remove the trigger on the modal :(

Comment: You can change your markup so the modal backdrop is a sibling of the actual modal instead of the parent.

Comment: That should work, but I have found a solution using the "target" event modifier. Please let me know if this is correct/idiomatic.